# How do I get my pre-order bonus content?

Tags: mass-effect-3

This may be a silly question, but where do I enter my pre-order code in order to access the downloadable content? I don't have the collector's edition, just the standard pre-order and the code that came with it, but I'm not prompted to enter it nor can I find mention of it in the DLC menu.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just plug it into the origin key box.

[image]

This is what I did, and it worked seamlessly.

[This video](http://youtu.be/JfRgYvA6Kqw) shows how.

Comment: This answer assumes the PC version is the version in use, of course.

Answer (score 1):

On the Xbox 360 version, you simply type your pre order code into the "Redeem a Code" section of your Xbox dashboard. This will redeem your pre order bonus and download into to your Xbox 360 console.

Answer (score 1):

For PC you open up origin and go to the settings menu (indicated by a gear) then go down to 'Redeem Product Code', enter the code then download the content.

For Xbox press the guide button in the center of the controller, go to the very left and there should be a 'Redeem Code' option, select this then enter your code followed by a download of the content.

For PS3 go to PlayStation store and at the top right should be a 'Redeem Code' option (never would have guessed that would ya), enter the code followed by the download.

This will only work with unique codes that haven't been used before.

Answer (score 0):

To redeem your bonus content, you need a BioWare Social Account:

> 1. Visit http://social.bioware.com/redeem.
> 2. Create or login with your BioWare Social account.
> 3. Enter your promo code and select the Redeem 
>       Code button.
> 4. Follow the on-screen instructions to install and
>       access your bonus content.

Comment: Note that assuming you're on the PC version don't create a new account for BSN, your Origin account will work to login and will ensure that you register the DLC on the right account.