# How to unlock the M55-Argus Rifle as a pre-order on Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3, pc

I had pre-ordered Mass Effect 3 on Origin and as a pre-order you got a bonus rifle. How do I go about unlocking it. I have completed the campaign and not found the rifle.

I have an unlock code from EA in my inbox however I cant find anywhere to input the code in the game?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: As a console owner, I received an email with the unlock code.

Comment: And I must not have been 100% awake, as I didn't see you also received that email.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get my pre-order bonus content?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55882/how-do-i-get-my-pre-order-bonus-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should have been a card included in the <strike>Origin</strike> Omni-blade box with a code to unlock the M55-Argus (not your online pass code on the back of the manual, it's on a separate card). It is only available for download via the EA servers, you do not find it in game.

When I per-ordered Origin they forgot to put it in the box, so if it's not there go back to the store you bought if from and they will arrange to get one for you.

If it seems like too much hassle, don't bother.  The M55 is powerful but the recoil is horrendous and IMO it is the most worthless gun in the game.

Comment: I dont have a box, I bought this as a digital copy!

Comment: I just had another look at my box and it says 'Omniblade edition' not 'Origin' so that's my bad.  Perhaps you should check with your vendor because from what I have read it differs from retailer to retailer.

Comment: Origin I bought it on :S

Answer (score 3):

> I have an unlock code from EA in my inbox however I cant find anywhere to input the code in the game?

This is because you don't input it in the game. To quote my answer from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/55885/1393):

> The easiest way is to just plug it into the origin key box.
>
> [image]
>
> This is what I did, and it worked seamlessly.
>
> [This video](http://youtu.be/JfRgYvA6Kqw) shows how.